# where does rails get information about gem path and gem info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Do I set this in .gemrc, or in .bashrc or both or neither, etc?

It's not really clear.

What happens if .gemrc says one thing, and .bashrc says another?

Answer (score 0):

Rails itself doesn't know about the gem path, as it's essentially a framework. Tools like Bundler, RVM and rbenv help you setup the gem path in environment variables.

If you get confused about the loading order, perhaps you should resort to [RVM](http://rvm.io/).

Or if you really want to do it yourself, first check the manual below:

```
% mkdir ~/.gems
% export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
% gem help environment

Usage: gem environment [arg] [options]

  Common Options:
    -h, --help                       Get help on this command
    -V, --[no-]verbose               Set the verbose level of output
    -q, --quiet                      Silence commands
        --config-file FILE           Use this config file instead of default
        --backtrace                  Show stack backtrace on errors
        --debug                      Turn on Ruby debugging


  Arguments:
    packageversion  display the package version
    gemdir          display the path where gems are installed
    gempath         display path used to search for gems
    version         display the gem format version
    remotesources   display the remote gem servers
           display everything

  Summary:
    Display information about the RubyGems environment

  Description:
    The RubyGems environment can be controlled through command line arguments,
    gemrc files, environment variables and built-in defaults.

    Command line argument defaults and some RubyGems defaults can be set in
    ~/.gemrc file for individual users and a /etc/gemrc for all users.  A gemrc
    is a YAML file with the following YAML keys:

      :sources: A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from
      :verbose: Verbosity of the gem command.  false, true, and :really are the
                levels
      :update_sources: Enable/disable automatic updating of repository metadata
      :backtrace: Print backtrace when RubyGems encounters an error
      :bulk_threshold: Switch to a bulk update when this many sources are out of
                       date (legacy setting)
      :gempath: The paths in which to look for gems
      gem_command: A string containing arguments for the specified gem command

    Example:

      :verbose: false
      install: --no-wrappers
      update: --no-wrappers

    RubyGems' default local repository can be overriden with the GEM_PATH and
    GEM_HOME environment variables.  GEM_HOME sets the default repository to
    install into.  GEM_PATH allows multiple local repositories to be searched
    for
    gems.

    If you are behind a proxy server, RubyGems uses the HTTP_PROXY,
    HTTP_PROXY_USER and HTTP_PROXY_PASS environment variables to discover the
    proxy server.

    If you are packaging RubyGems all of RubyGems' defaults are in
    lib/rubygems/defaults.rb.  You may override these in
    lib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
```

Make sure to type in `gem env` in command line to see your current gem related information.

Comment: So where does Ruby get the gem path? Only environment variables? The reason I ask is because I thought I could set this in .gemrc, but there seems to be a disconnect.

Comment: Basically Ruby gets the gem path from environment variable GEM_PATH. Please check the updated answer, I've pasted a manual on that, should explain this clearly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It seems as though the default GEM_HOME is compiled into ruby, and this can be overridden with environment vars.

Comment: `export GEM_HOME=~/.gems` in .bashrc should do the trick, doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: This is still doesn't really answer the question. The question is about .gemrc, GEM_PATH, and .bashrc / _profile. After my own research it seems that each ruby install has a default GEM_HOME internally configured. If there is an environment variable set when it runs, it will use that. And the .gemrc doesn't affect anything except where gem installs gems (and can't be relied on to set any environment vars itself - which wasn't clear to me).